# Cron Job fires twice in Serverless using AWS Lambda

Tags: cron, aws-lambda, serverless

I am running a Cron Job which runs every Sunday at 10:00am UTC

It pushes a Text Message to a Telegram Group

Here's my [full code](https://github.com/deadcoder0904/lessons-of-hn-telegram-bot)

Relevant parts below -

## serverless.yml

```
service: lessons-of-hn-telegram-bot

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  environment:
    BOT_API_KEY: ${file(./env.json):BOT_API_KEY}
    CHANNEL_ID: ${file(./env.json):CHANNEL_ID}

functions:
  cron:
    handler: handler.run
    description: Cron job that runs every Sunday at 10 am UTC
    events:
      - schedule: cron(0 10 ? * SUN *)
```

## handler.js

```
const axios = require("axios");

const { lessonsOfHN } = require("./src/lessonsOfHN");

exports.run = async (event, context, callback) => {
  const time = new Date();
  console.log(`Your cron function "${context.functionName}" ran at ${time}`);

  const lesson = await lessonsOfHN();
  const ENDPOINT = `https://api.telegram.org/bot${
    process.env.BOT_API_KEY
  }/sendMessage`;

  await axios({
    method: "get",
    url: ENDPOINT,
    data: {
      chat_id: process.env.CHANNEL_ID,
      parse_mode: "markdown",
      disable_web_page_preview: true,
      text: lesson
    }
  });

  callback(null, { lesson, success: true });
};
```

Nowhere in the code a request is sent to Telegram twice ,i.e, `axios` is only written once

The logs I got says the cronjob ran twice once at `10:00:09 am` & at `10:01:08 am`

I am using Serverless Framework with AWS Lambda

How to make sure it only runs once? Since people get 2 messages in the telegram group because of this :(

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50396250/serverless-cron-job-firing-twice?noredirect=1#comment87993413_50396250)

Comment: Read the comments at that link

Comment: Ohh I read it before posting. But what's the solution? If there is any? Because we can't maintain the state so I was thinking if anyone more experienced has an answer. That's why I posted it :)

Also, you said in that answer if its failing once, then it might call again. For me, its not failing at all as its just 1 get request & the cron job runs again in 1 minute so there is no failing situation either

Comment: Did you also check the triggers in aws lambda console. I had once that they were 2 same triggers after deploying it with serverless

Comment: I don't know how to check in the AWS Lambda Console but I checked the logs from Serverless using `sls logs -f cron -t` which gives me all logs. In the Serverless Dashboard I only have 1 application which means it is the only one that can run. My code also has just 1 request which means no false positives. Feels sad that for no reason it gets executed twice :(